# Showing that $\mathbb{E}_c[p(a \mid b, c)] = p(a \mid b).$

Tags: probability

It's simple to show that *(note that all the expectations are wrt the marginal distribution of corresponding variable, e.g. $\mathbb{E}_b[f(b)] = \int f(b) p(b) \text{ d}b = \int f(b) (\int p(a, b, c) \text{ d} a \text{ d} c) \text{ d}b$)*

$$
\mathbb{E}_b[p(a \mid b)] = p(a),
$$

simply by evaluation as
$$
\mathbb{E}_b[p(a \mid b)] =  \int p(b) p(a 
 \mid b) \text{ d} b  = \int p(b) \frac{p(a, b)}{p(b)} \text{ d} b = p(a). 
$$

But I'm struggling in showing a conditional version of this in the form of

$$
\mathbb{E}_c[p(a \mid b, c)] = p(a \mid b).
$$

How to show the last relation? Surely it must hold since it is just a conditional version of the first equation.

Comment: What is $p$ and $\mathbb{E}_b$?

Comment: @user159517 $p$ is the density of a continuous random variable over three variables; $\mathbb{E}_b := \mathbb{E}_{b \sim p(b)}$, where $p(b)$ is the marginalized $p$

Comment: If $p$ is a density, then your expression does not seem make any sense. Could you please add the original question with all the random variables in question?

Comment: @PeterKeller Hmm, could you elaborate why this does not seem to make sense? Do the first and second equations make sense? A, B, C are real random variables. There is no further specification, as I have encountered this question "in the wild".

Comment: Then please define, what the expectation of a measure is. I can only guess what you mean. Is this the first equation: $E[E[A|B]]=E[A]$? (conditional expectation)

Comment: @PeterKeller I see your point now; I'm afraid I'm not familiar with measure-theoretic concepts to define things to the level of precision you ask. By expectation I only mean the "standard" integration over the set of values over reals. In that case the first equation is $\mathbb{E}[p(a \mid b)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} p(B = b) p(A = a \mid B = b) \text{ d} b$. Regarding the second comment: no, I don't think so. I'm simply evaluating an expected value of a function that happens to be the density with respect to the conditioned variable

Comment: I see, you are trying to compute marginals? Expectation is not something i would use here...

Comment: The expectation is crucial here -- I only need to go from the expectation (over the conditional) to the density, which so happens to be a marginal. The expectation is part of the problem, not merely my own injection. Unless you argue that I should replace expectation with its definition as I did in my previous comment? I would edit my question then.

Comment: Yes, please edit your question. I do not see the sense of expectation here. It is only defined for random variables.

Comment: @PeterKeller But the transformed variable $B \mapsto p(a \mid B)$ is valid random variable? All I'm doing is taking the expectation of this transformed random variable

Comment: No, that's not a random variable.

Comment: @PeterKeller Why not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136788/discussion-between-peter-keller-and-flight-booker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the answer below, the equality you want to show holds if $c$ is independent of $b$. With your formal notation:
\begin{align}
p(a\mid b) &= \frac{p(a,b)}{p(b)}\\
&=\int \frac{p(a,b,c)}{p(b)} dc\\
&=\int \frac{p(a \mid b, c)p(b, c)}{p(b)} dc\\
&=\int \frac{p(a \mid b, c)p(c \mid b)p(b)}{p(b)} dc\\
&=\int p(a \mid b, c)p(c \mid b) dc \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{c\mid b}[p(a\mid b,c)]
\end{align}
If $c$ is independent of $b$, then $p(c\mid b) = p(c)$ and you have what you want.

**Edit:** see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/418295/marginalize-probability-with-three-variables) for the discrete case

Comment: @Gare, I still do not see, how this is an expectation...

Comment: In the notation above $p(a)$ is the pdf of some real-valued r.v. $A$, and $\mathbb{E}_a$ is the expectation wrt the measure induced by $A$. For an integrable function $f$, we have $\mathbb{E}_a[f(\cdot)] = \int f(a) p(a) da$. If you replace $f$ by the pdf $p(b\mid a)$ of the random variable $B\mid A$ and varying the condition, you obtain $\mathbb{E}_{a}[p(b \mid \cdot)] = \int p(b \mid a) p(a) d a$. All is very formal though.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed that this has to hold yet tried to prove it.. Turns out I overlooked an assumption in the original problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments of the OP, I can just guess the question. So, let's assume $A$, $B$ and $C$ are random variables with densities on $\mathbb R$. Then the conditional density of $A$ given $B$ and $C$ is defined as
$$f_{A|B=b,C=c}(a):=\frac{f_{A,B,C}(a,b,c)}{f_{B,C}(b,c)}$$
where the right hand side is the ratio of the known joint densities.

Then the questions is, what happens if we integrate over the values of $C$ and its density:
$$\int_{\mathbb R}f_C(c)f_{A|B=b,C=c}(a)\,dc=\int_{\mathbb R}f_C(c)\frac{f_{A,B,C}(a,b,c)}{f_{B,C}(b,c)}\,dc=f_{A|B=b}(a)$$ only if $B$ and $C$ are independent, i.e. $f_{B,C}(b,c)=f_B(b)f_C(c)$.